# Css mouseover highlight with table

Tags: html, css

I want to highlight my table rows when I hover over them. I had the hover and highlight behavior to work using CSS. But after I applied the styles, the table rows started wrapping.

Here is a screenshot of [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SShqS.png) I applied the CSS, and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiTJY.png). Note how the table rows are wrapping in the *after* screenshot.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

```css
.table_class tr {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  background: #2098D1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.table_class tr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.table_class tr:hover,
.table_class tr:focus,
.table_class tr:active {
  color: white;
}

.table_class tr:hover:before,
.table_class tr:focus:before,
.table_class tr:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- TOP -->
    <table class="table table-bordered table_class">
      <tbody>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="child_meaning">Meaning of Aadi</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Name : </td>
          <td>Aadi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Meaning : </td>
          <td>Adornment, Beginning, Perfect, Most important, Ornament, Unequalled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gender : </td>
          <td>Boy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Numerology : </td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Syllables : </td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Religion : </td>
          <td>Hindu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rashi : </td>
          <td>Mesha</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Nakshatra : </td>
          <td>Krithika</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: Please add your code here in question.

Comment: @yogen darji  i have added code. please check

Comment: If you could further edit your question to include the HTML in the question as well, instead of a link to it, that'd be best. On the edit page, use the little icon of a piece of paper with brackets on it to include your HTML and CSS in a Stack Snippet that we can run to see the problem. And also please clarify what exactly your desired effect is. You've mentioned there's a problem but haven't said specifically what it is, so it's hard for us to know how much of the way it is now is by design and how much is a problem you're trying to fix.

Comment: @cjl750 HTML code https://pastebin.com/A9RRcTQm

Comment: @Unidan, I saw the link. I mean insert the code itself into your question, not a link to it. Insert it as a stack snippet using the icon of the piece of paper with brackets on it, making sure what when you hit the "run" button on the stack snippet it actually *reproduces* your problem. That will let people focus on the code and not have to reference multiple outside links. We want questions here to be self-contained so that if your pastebin link breaks in the future your question still makes sense on its own.

Comment: @cjl750 i have edit post. Please check it.

Comment: So I presume the problem is that the gender row doesn't highlight the whole thing?

Comment: @cjl750 please solve this error and provide me code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your screenshots, I assume the issue is that your table rows start wrapping after you implement the hover state? That's because you set `display: inline-block` to your `<tr>` elements. You can fix it by changing the display property to something that doesn't turn your rows into inline elements. Something like this:

```css
.table_class tbody>tr {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  background: #2098D1;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.table_class tbody>tr:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.table_class tbody>tr:hover,
.table_class tbody>tr:focus,
.table_class tbody>tr:active {
  color: white;
}

.table_class tbody>tr:hover:before,
.table_class tbody>tr:focus:before,
.table_class tbody>tr:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- TOP -->
    <table class="table table-bordered table_class">
      <tbody>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="child_meaning">Meaning of Aadi</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Name : </td>
          <td>Aadi</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Meaning : </td>
          <td>Adornment, Beginning, Perfect, Most important, Ornament, Unequalled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gender : </td>
          <td>Boy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Numerology : </td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Syllables : </td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Religion : </td>
          <td>Hindu</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Rashi : </td>
          <td>Mesha</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Nakshatra : </td>
          <td>Krithika</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps. Also, I scoped your row styles so that they are not applied to the table header.